# Controlling manul cancellation for pipelines in ADF

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Some of the pipelines we have created start and conclude inserting/updating some register at the begining and at the end in our process table. However, recently some users got the role that allowe them to cancel the pipelines (client's policy). We wonder if there is a way to indicate in ADF the execution of a process when this event ocurrs (status = cancellation). We need to keep our table sincronized.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Cancelled pipeline run metrics under Alerts and Metrics should be useful. You can create an alert when a pipeline is cancelled. Your notifications can be in the form of emails, SMS, azure app push, or voice call.

[As seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSAI1.png)

If you know how to write Kusto (its very easy to learn), you can also write a custom alert using pipeline metrics logs in Log Analytics.

If you meant in the question parameterizing, not notifying cancellations, for example as in dataflow expression builder; system variables on the pipeline level in the below article does not list pipeline trigger end status as variable:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-system-variables

The reason is that we are parameterizing something before the fact it happens(cancels), so log analytics would be helpful in this case too I think. Query in log analytics and filter cancellations, then you can move from there. To add functionality, such as when you want to do something when a cancellation occurs, you can create an alert rule in log analytics, and add action when an action group is triggered, such as an Azure function or webhook.

To connect log analytics to ADF, you need to enable diagnostics setting, and send it to log analytics, there are videos on web explaining how to do that.

Of course as always, you can also create a support ticket with ADF to make %100 sure it is not supported as a system variable.